# Upgrade PCRE lib on AWS EC2 Linux AMI

Tags: php, amazon-ec2, aws, amazon-linux

I would like to update the default PCRE library of my AWS EC2 Linux instance. Current version is 8.21 2011-12-12.

I tried with the following guides:

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=234930
https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Updating_to_PCRE_8.33_or_Higher

The installation was successful (`make check` returned all the OK test) but it seems that PHP is still not using the correct version of PCRE.
I guess it is something related to the `link` step of the guide in which the 32 bit lib is liked instead of the 64 one used, but I am not very sure how to fix it. Apache and machine were rebooted after the installation.

Any suggestion on how should I proceed with this?

Thank you in advance

*Additional info*

```
    $ uname -a
        Linux ip-10-0-3-82 4.9.75-25.55.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jan 5 23:50:27 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

    $ sudo yum install pcre
        Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
        amzn-main                                                                                                                                                    | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
        amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                 | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
        Package pcre-8.21-7.7.amzn1.x86_64 already installed and latest version
        Nothing to do

    $ pcretest -C
        PCRE version 8.41 2017-07-05
        Compiled with
          8-bit support
          UTF-8 support
          16-bit support
          UTF-16 support
          32-bit support
          UTF-32 support
          Unicode properties support
          No just-in-time compiler support
          Newline sequence is LF
          \R matches all Unicode newlines
          Internal link size = 2
          POSIX malloc threshold = 10
          Parentheses nest limit = 250
          Default match limit = 10000000
          Default recursion depth limit = 10000000
          Match recursion uses stack

    $ ldd /usr/bin/php
            linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffe23d73000)
            libcrypt.so.1 => /lib64/libcrypt.so.1 (0x00007ff4cd67f000)
            libresolv.so.2 => /lib64/libresolv.so.2 (0x00007ff4cd465000)
            libedit.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libedit.so.0 (0x00007ff4cd236000)
            libncurses.so.5 => /lib64/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007ff4cd010000)
            libtinfo.so.5 => /lib64/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007ff4ccdef000)
            libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007ff4cca6c000)
            libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007ff4cc856000)
            libpcre.so.0 => /lib64/libpcre.so.0 (0x00007ff4cc5fe000)
            librt.so.1 => /lib64/librt.so.1 (0x00007ff4cc3f6000)
            libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007ff4cc0f4000)
            libdl.so.2 => /lib64/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff4cbef0000)
            libnsl.so.1 => /lib64/libnsl.so.1 (0x00007ff4cbcd7000)
            libxml2.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2 (0x00007ff4cb96f000)
            libgssapi_krb5.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2 (0x00007ff4cb722000)
            libkrb5.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5.so.3 (0x00007ff4cb43a000)
            libk5crypto.so.3 => /usr/lib64/libk5crypto.so.3 (0x00007ff4cb207000)
            libcom_err.so.2 => /usr/lib64/libcom_err.so.2 (0x00007ff4cb004000)
            libssl.so.10 => /lib64/libssl.so.10 (0x00007ff4cad93000)
            libcrypto.so.10 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.10 (0x00007ff4ca935000)
            libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ff4ca71f000)
            libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff4ca35b000)
            libfreebl3.so => /lib64/libfreebl3.so (0x00007ff4ca159000)
            /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff4cd8b6000)
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff4c9f3d000)
            liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib64/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007ff4c9d19000)
            libkrb5support.so.0 => /usr/lib64/libkrb5support.so.0 (0x00007ff4c9b0b000)
            libkeyutils.so.1 => /lib64/libkeyutils.so.1 (0x00007ff4c9908000)
            libselinux.so.1 => /usr/lib64/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ff4c96e7000)

    $ ll -ll /lib64 | grep pcre
    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 Nov 20 22:11 libpcre.so.0 -> libpcre.so.0.0.1
    -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  359688 May 27  2015 libpcre.so.0.0.1

$ sudo make install
    make  install-am
    make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
    make[2]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib'
     /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libpcre.la libpcre16.la libpcre32.la libpcreposix.la libpcrecpp.la '/usr/lib'
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre.so.1.2.9 /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.9
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre.so.1.2.9 libpcre.so.1 || { rm -f libpcre.so.1 && ln -s libpcre.so.1.2.9 libpcre.so.1; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre.so.1.2.9 libpcre.so || { rm -f libpcre.so && ln -s libpcre.so.1.2.9 libpcre.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre.lai /usr/lib/libpcre.la
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre16.so.0.2.9 /usr/lib/libpcre16.so.0.2.9
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre16.so.0.2.9 libpcre16.so.0 || { rm -f libpcre16.so.0 && ln -s libpcre16.so.0.2.9 libpcre16.so.0; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre16.so.0.2.9 libpcre16.so || { rm -f libpcre16.so && ln -s libpcre16.so.0.2.9 libpcre16.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre16.lai /usr/lib/libpcre16.la
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre32.so.0.0.9 /usr/lib/libpcre32.so.0.0.9
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre32.so.0.0.9 libpcre32.so.0 || { rm -f libpcre32.so.0 && ln -s libpcre32.so.0.0.9 libpcre32.so.0; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcre32.so.0.0.9 libpcre32.so || { rm -f libpcre32.so && ln -s libpcre32.so.0.0.9 libpcre32.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcre32.lai /usr/lib/libpcre32.la
    libtool: warning: relinking 'libpcreposix.la'
    libtool: install: (cd /home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41; /bin/sh "/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41/libtool"  --silent --tag CC --mode=relink gcc -fvisibility=hidden -g -O2 -version-info 0:5:0 -o libpcreposix.la -rpath /usr/lib libpcreposix_la-pcreposix.lo libpcre.la )
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcreposix.so.0.0.5T /usr/lib/libpcreposix.so.0.0.5
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcreposix.so.0.0.5 libpcreposix.so.0 || { rm -f libpcreposix.so.0 && ln -s libpcreposix.so.0.0.5 libpcreposix.so.0; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcreposix.so.0.0.5 libpcreposix.so || { rm -f libpcreposix.so && ln -s libpcreposix.so.0.0.5 libpcreposix.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcreposix.lai /usr/lib/libpcreposix.la
    libtool: warning: relinking 'libpcrecpp.la'
    libtool: install: (cd /home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41; /bin/sh "/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41/libtool"  --silent --tag CXX --mode=relink g++ -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O2 -version-info 0:1:0 -o libpcrecpp.la -rpath /usr/lib libpcrecpp_la-pcrecpp.lo libpcrecpp_la-pcre_scanner.lo libpcrecpp_la-pcre_stringpiece.lo libpcre.la )
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1T /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1 libpcrecpp.so.0 || { rm -f libpcrecpp.so.0 && ln -s libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1 libpcrecpp.so.0; }; })
    libtool: install: (cd /usr/lib && { ln -s -f libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1 libpcrecpp.so || { rm -f libpcrecpp.so && ln -s libpcrecpp.so.0.0.1 libpcrecpp.so; }; })
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libpcrecpp.lai /usr/lib/libpcrecpp.la
    libtool: finish: PATH="/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin" ldconfig -n /usr/lib
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Libraries have been installed in:
       /usr/lib

    If you ever happen to want to link against installed libraries
    in a given directory, LIBDIR, you must either use libtool, and
    specify the full pathname of the library, or use the '-LLIBDIR'
    flag during linking and do at least one of the following:
       - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_LIBRARY_PATH' environment variable
         during execution
       - add LIBDIR to the 'LD_RUN_PATH' environment variable
         during linking
       - use the '-Wl,-rpath -Wl,LIBDIR' linker flag
       - have your system administrator add LIBDIR to '/etc/ld.so.conf'

    See any operating system documentation about shared libraries for
    more information, such as the ld(1) and ld.so(8) manual pages.
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
      /bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c pcretest pcregrep '/usr/bin'
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/pcretest /usr/bin/pcretest
    libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/pcregrep /usr/bin/pcregrep
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/bin'
     /usr/bin/install -c pcre-config '/usr/bin'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/pcre.txt doc/pcre-config.txt doc/pcregrep.txt doc/pcretest.txt AUTHORS COPYING ChangeLog LICENCE NEWS README '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41/html'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/html/NON-AUTOTOOLS-BUILD.txt doc/html/README.txt doc/html/index.html doc/html/pcre-config.html doc/html/pcre.html doc/html/pcre16.html doc/html/pcre32.html doc/html/pcre_assign_jit_stack.html doc/html/pcre_compile.html doc/html/pcre_compile2.html doc/html/pcre_config.html doc/html/pcre_copy_named_substring.html doc/html/pcre_copy_substring.html doc/html/pcre_dfa_exec.html doc/html/pcre_exec.html doc/html/pcre_free_study.html doc/html/pcre_free_substring.html doc/html/pcre_free_substring_list.html doc/html/pcre_fullinfo.html doc/html/pcre_get_named_substring.html doc/html/pcre_get_stringnumber.html doc/html/pcre_get_stringtable_entries.html doc/html/pcre_get_substring.html doc/html/pcre_get_substring_list.html doc/html/pcre_jit_exec.html doc/html/pcre_jit_stack_alloc.html doc/html/pcre_jit_stack_free.html doc/html/pcre_maketables.html doc/html/pcre_pattern_to_host_byte_order.html doc/html/pcre_refcount.html doc/html/pcre_study.html doc/html/pcre_utf16_to_host_byte_order.html doc/html/pcre_utf32_to_host_byte_order.html doc/html/pcre_version.html doc/html/pcreapi.html doc/html/pcrebuild.html doc/html/pcrecallout.html doc/html/pcrecompat.html doc/html/pcredemo.html doc/html/pcregrep.html '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41/html'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/html/pcrejit.html doc/html/pcrelimits.html doc/html/pcrematching.html doc/html/pcrepartial.html doc/html/pcrepattern.html doc/html/pcreperform.html doc/html/pcreposix.html doc/html/pcreprecompile.html doc/html/pcresample.html doc/html/pcrestack.html doc/html/pcresyntax.html doc/html/pcretest.html doc/html/pcreunicode.html '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41/html'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41/html'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/html/pcrecpp.html '/usr/share/doc/pcre-8.41/html'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pcreposix.h pcrecpp.h pcre_scanner.h '/usr/include'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man1'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/pcre-config.1 doc/pcregrep.1 doc/pcretest.1 '/usr/share/man/man1'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/share/man/man3'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/pcre.3 doc/pcre16.3 doc/pcre32.3 doc/pcre_assign_jit_stack.3 doc/pcre_compile.3 doc/pcre_compile2.3 doc/pcre_config.3 doc/pcre_copy_named_substring.3 doc/pcre_copy_substring.3 doc/pcre_dfa_exec.3 doc/pcre_exec.3 doc/pcre_free_study.3 doc/pcre_free_substring.3 doc/pcre_free_substring_list.3 doc/pcre_fullinfo.3 doc/pcre_get_named_substring.3 doc/pcre_get_stringnumber.3 doc/pcre_get_stringtable_entries.3 doc/pcre_get_substring.3 doc/pcre_get_substring_list.3 doc/pcre_jit_exec.3 doc/pcre_jit_stack_alloc.3 doc/pcre_jit_stack_free.3 doc/pcre_maketables.3 doc/pcre_pattern_to_host_byte_order.3 doc/pcre_refcount.3 doc/pcre_study.3 doc/pcre_utf16_to_host_byte_order.3 doc/pcre_utf32_to_host_byte_order.3 doc/pcre_version.3 doc/pcreapi.3 doc/pcrebuild.3 doc/pcrecallout.3 doc/pcrecompat.3 doc/pcredemo.3 doc/pcrejit.3 doc/pcrelimits.3 doc/pcrematching.3 doc/pcrepartial.3 doc/pcrepattern.3 '/usr/share/man/man3'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 doc/pcreperform.3 doc/pcreposix.3 doc/pcreprecompile.3 doc/pcresample.3 doc/pcrestack.3 doc/pcresyntax.3 doc/pcreunicode.3 doc/pcrecpp.3 '/usr/share/man/man3'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/include'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 pcre.h pcrecpparg.h pcre_stringpiece.h '/usr/include'
     /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
     /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 libpcre.pc libpcreposix.pc libpcre16.pc libpcre32.pc libpcrecpp.pc '/usr/lib/pkgconfig'
    make  install-data-hook
    make[3]: Entering directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
    ln -sf pcre_assign_jit_stack.3       /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_assign_jit_stack.3
    ln -sf pcre_compile.3            /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_compile.3
    ln -sf pcre_compile2.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_compile2.3
    ln -sf pcre_config.3             /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_config.3
    ln -sf pcre_copy_named_substring.3   /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_copy_named_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_copy_substring.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_copy_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_dfa_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_dfa_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_study.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_free_study.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_substring.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_free_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_substring_list.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_free_substring_list.3
    ln -sf pcre_fullinfo.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_fullinfo.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_named_substring.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_get_named_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_stringnumber.3       /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_get_stringnumber.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_stringtable_entries.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_get_stringtable_entries.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_substring.3      /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_get_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_substring_list.3     /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_get_substring_list.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_jit_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_stack_alloc.3        /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_jit_stack_alloc.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_stack_free.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_jit_stack_free.3
    ln -sf pcre_maketables.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_maketables.3
    ln -sf pcre_pattern_to_host_byte_order.3 /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_pattern_to_host_byte_order.3
    ln -sf pcre_refcount.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_refcount.3
    ln -sf pcre_study.3          /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_study.3
    ln -sf pcre_utf16_to_host_byte_order.3   /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_utf16_to_host_byte_order.3
    ln -sf pcre_version.3            /usr/share/man/man3/pcre16_version.3
    ln -sf pcre_assign_jit_stack.3       /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_assign_jit_stack.3
    ln -sf pcre_compile.3            /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_compile.3
    ln -sf pcre_compile2.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_compile2.3
    ln -sf pcre_config.3             /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_config.3
    ln -sf pcre_copy_named_substring.3   /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_copy_named_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_copy_substring.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_copy_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_dfa_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_dfa_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_study.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_free_study.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_substring.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_free_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_free_substring_list.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_free_substring_list.3
    ln -sf pcre_fullinfo.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_fullinfo.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_named_substring.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_get_named_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_stringnumber.3       /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_get_stringnumber.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_stringtable_entries.3    /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_get_stringtable_entries.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_substring.3      /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_get_substring.3
    ln -sf pcre_get_substring_list.3     /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_get_substring_list.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_exec.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_jit_exec.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_stack_alloc.3        /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_jit_stack_alloc.3
    ln -sf pcre_jit_stack_free.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_jit_stack_free.3
    ln -sf pcre_maketables.3         /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_maketables.3
    ln -sf pcre_pattern_to_host_byte_order.3 /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_pattern_to_host_byte_order.3
    ln -sf pcre_refcount.3           /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_refcount.3
    ln -sf pcre_study.3          /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_study.3
    ln -sf pcre_utf32_to_host_byte_order.3   /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_utf32_to_host_byte_order.3
    ln -sf pcre_version.3            /usr/share/man/man3/pcre32_version.3
    make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
    make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
    make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ec2-user/pcre-8.41'
    [ec2-user@ip-10-0-3-82 pcre-8.41]$ sudo mv -v /usr/lib/libpcre.so.* /lib 
    ‘/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1’ -> ‘/lib/libpcre.so.1’
    ‘/usr/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.9’ -> ‘/lib/libpcre.so.1.2.9’
    [ec2-user@ip-10-0-3-82 pcre-8.41]$ sudo ln -sfv ../../lib/$(readlink /usr/lib/libpcre.so) /usr/lib/libpcre.so
    ‘/usr/lib/libpcre.so’ -> ‘../../lib/libpcre.so.1.2.9’
$ sudo service httpd restart
        Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
        Starting httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
```

*phpinfo.php*
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In many cases, the linked-to method of updating a library works (subject to stomping all over your package managers feelings, though you also run the risk of creating more problems than you solve if you are not familiar with building packages).

PHP comes bundled with its own copy of PCRE, so you *might* be running an ancient version of PHP (unlikely, as even php-5.4 was bundled with pcre-8.37). In that case replacing a system PCRE would have no effect, but the `ldd` output confirms you are using the system PCRE.

You are using an old system PCRE (AMI is RHEL derived, libraries are only updated on major releases). The problem then is that PCRE v8.30 [introduced some API changes](https://vcs.pcre.org/pcre/code/tags/pcre-8.30/NEWS?revision=910&view=markup), and this triggered an update in library version ([as per convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soname) as an API function `pcre_info()` was removed). For < 8.30 the library will be called `libpcre.so.0` and for ≥ v8.30 it will be `libpcre.so.1`.

```
$ diff -u pcre-8.21/libpcre.la pcre-8.30/libpcre.la
[...]
 # The name that we can dlopen(3).
-dlname='libpcre.so.0'
+dlname='libpcre.so.1'

 # Names of this library.
-library_names='libpcre.so.0.0.1 libpcre.so.0 libpcre.so'
+library_names='libpcre.so.1.0.0 libpcre.so.1 libpcre.so'
```

You can confirm this from the install log you pasted.

Assuming you're using the system PHP, it would have been compiled and linked against the system version `libpcre.so.0`, so you are correct in that linking is the issue, but it is the linking of PHP. It will never use the `libpcre.so.1` you have installed. (If you search hard enough you'll find people advocating some symlink trickery to get around the problem, I don't recommend this, *the API changed and the version changed for a reason*.)

In the example you link to the author was upgrading from 8.31 to 8.33, so no problem was encountered.

Your simplest choices are to check if newer PHP packages are available which use a newer PCRE; or update your AMI version. (A less simple option is to build your own PHP, generally not recommended, and included here only for completeness. Start with the `configure` details in the output of `phpinfo()` and make sure to *omit* the option `--with-pcre-regex=/usr` or similar, to prefer the more up to date bundled PCRE. Be prepared to install *lots* of dev packages...)